# Matrix for Lagged Dependent Variables in TSCS (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, matrix

Does anyone have any thoughts on ways to create a matrix to identify one-period lagged dependent variable for use in tscs/panel analysis where the panel size varies? I can make this when there is a constant sample size, but it gets trickier (for me) with varying sample sizes. For example, if I had a 3 actor (A, B, C) 3 Period (1, 2, 3) model, but C was only present for the last 2 periods I would want:

```
   A1 B1 A2 B2 C2 A3 B3 C3  
A1 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  
B1 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  
A2 1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  
B2 0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  
C2 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  
A3 0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  
B3 0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  
C3 0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0
```

I'd imagine it's just a loop which constructs an identity matrix for each panel-year, but I'm just not sure how this notation would look.  (Just for clarity the matrix need not hold the values of the lagged-dv, merely identify the relevant observations) Thanks for any help!

Comment: Could you elaborate on the kind of input data you have? Do you know for each actor at which period he starts showing up in the model?

Comment: Yes, for example, let's say you were using international macro data from WW2 on. In this example several countries wouldn't be in the sample for the entire period (e.g Georgia) and would only enter following independence.  I'm not sure what type of further elaboration you're looking for beyond that (the initial source data would be like a Stata, R, excel type of data frame with the columns representing variables and the rows representing observations).  Thanks!

Comment: That's quite clear, my question was more along the lines of you input such data into matlab. E.g. is it just a list of country names and periods when they become part of the table or what?